# pam_radius_auth: Failed to open RADIUS IPv6 socket

Tags: networking, ssh, connection

I am using Ubuntu22.04.3 LTS. We've encountered the following error after disabling IPv6. Previously, it was working fine when IPv6 was enabled. However, in our environment, IPv6 is not in use:

"pam_radius_auth: Failed to open RADIUS IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol."

My pam authentication configuration detail

**vim /etc/pam_radius_auth.conf**

```
# server[:port] shared_secret timeout (s) source_ip vrf
#127.0.0.1 secret 3
#other-server other-secret 5 192.168.1.10 vrf-blue
#[2001:0db8:85a3::4]:1812 other6-secret 3 [2001:0db8:85a3::3] vrf-red
#other-other-server other-other-secret 5 0 vrf-blue
10.174.30.42     ftre$K98*TEttg^V5#CpC      5
10.175.30.30     ftre$K98*TEttg^V5#CpC      5
10.184.30.1      ftre$K98*TEttg^V5#CpC      5
```

**My sshd configuration details vim /etc/pam.d/sshd**

```
# Standard Un*x authentication.

#@include common-auth
auth required pam_radius_auth.so
```

Could you please help to fix the issue?